# Debian Squeeze: hide xorg start messages

Tags: debian, x-server

I have setup up my box so that it I automatically login as root via the command line interface. in `bash.bashrc` I have these commands: `startx ./run.sh` in the command line. Right before it starts the xserver, it displays the following information:

```
        X.Org X Server 1.7.7
        Release Date: 2010-05-04
        X Protocol Version 11 Revision 0
        Build Operating System: Linux 3.0.0-1-amd64 x86_64 Debian
        Current Operating System: Linux debian 2.6.32-5-amd64 #1 SMP Fri Feb 15   15:39:52 UTC 2013
        Kernel command  line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-5-amd64 root=UUID=2c7e52a1-b10c-???????
        Build Date: 29 October 2011 06:58:14PM
        xorg-server 2:1.7.7.14 (Jaleo Christian jcristian@Debian.org)
        Current version of pixman: 0.16.4
        Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
            to make sure that you have the latest version.
        Markers: (--) problem, (==) from config file, (**) default setting, 
               (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) Informational, 
               (WW) warning, (EE) Error, (NI) Not Implemented, (??) unknown
        (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Wed Aug 29 10:50:12 2012/
        (==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
        (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
```

Since I have my application running right afterwards, I don't want the intermediate text appearing. I've look in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` to see if there is a setting that displays messages to the screen but nothing.

Q: Where would I need to go to disable the above messages from being displayed?

Comment: Hmm... `startx ./run.sh >/dev/null 2>&1`?

Comment: Why would you use bash.bashrc for this? Why not profile? If you use the former, an X instance will be launched every time a user opens a new shell!

Comment: why not profile? simply because I figured out how to do it with bash.bashrc     how would I set up the profile?

Comment: Martin von Wittich; thanks, that's what I wanted it to do!

Comment: @fifamaniac04: OK, I've posted it as an answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pipe the output (and STDERR) to `/dev/null`:

```
startx ./run.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: this works perfectly. Simple and clean.